# How to get ID of link that opened Fancybox3 within onComplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, fancybox, fancybox-3

I have seen what looks like it could be the solution to this issue in other questions on stackoverflow, but NONE of them have worked.

I am trying to get the innertext of the link that was clicked to open Fancybox:

> $("a.turnDateLink").each(function() {
>
> ```
>               var that = $(this);
>
>               $( "a.turnDateLink" ).fancybox({
>                   'type': 'modal',
>                   'onComplete': function() {
>
>                       var currentday = $(that).text();
>                       console.log(currentday);
>                   },
>                   'afterClose': clearCurrentDay,
>                   'fullScreen' : false
>               });
> ```
>
> });

It only returns the innerText of the last `a.turnDateLink.`  EVERY TIME! ugh.

Keep in mind that I would like to use the fancybox grouping with this.

See the Fancybox documentation to understand grouping: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#usage

> If you have a group of items, you can use the same attribute
>   data-fancybox value for each of them to create a gallery. Each group
>   should have a unique value:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check documentation about events - http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#events

The first examaple contains useful tips, including how to find clicked element:

```
onComplete: function( instance, slide ) {

    // Tip: Each event passes useful information within the event object:

    // Object containing references to interface elements
    // (background, buttons, caption, etc)
    // console.info( instance.$refs );

    // Current slide options
    // console.info( slide.opts );

    // Clicked element
    // console.info( slide.opts.$orig );

    // Reference to DOM element of the slide
    // console.info( slide.$slide );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.Change `$( "a.turnDateLink" )` to `that`.

```
$("a.turnDateLink").each(function() {

                  var that = $(this);

                  that.fancybox({
                      'type': 'modal',
                      'onComplete': function() {
                          $("#currentday").html('');

                          var currentday = that.text();
                          console.log(currentday);
                      },
                      'afterClose': clearCurrentDay,
                      'fullScreen' : false
                  });
    });
```

Comment: The issue with this is that you can not use the fancybox grouping when doing it this way. This causes each instance to use a different fancybox and you lose the ability to group them.  This is very close, but I am looking to use grouping.

Comment: i dont understand grouping means what is your expected output?

Comment: Please see my revised question.  Grouping is mentioned in the Fancybox documentation. Thanks for your time!